# Cisco redundancy modes

Tags: networking, cisco, router, switch, cisco-catalyst

I am using a Cisco 6500 series with an SSO redundancy configuration.  The show redundancy output is as follows:

```
             Hardware Mode = Duplex
Configured Redundancy Mode = sso
 Operating Redundancy Mode = rpr
          Maintenance Mode = Disabled
            Communications = Up
```

I would assume the device is operating in RPR mode although SSO is configured.  What could cause this?  Shouldn't the operating mode be SSO?

EDIT (show redundancy states):

```
   my state = 13 -ACTIVE
 peer state = 4  -STANDBY COLD
       Mode = Duplex
       Unit = Primary
    Unit ID = 5
    Redundancy Mode (Operational) = rpr
    Redundancy Mode (Configured)  = sso
    Redundancy State              = rpr

 Split Mode = Disabled
 Manual Swact = Enabled
 Communications = Up

  client count = 60
  client_notification_TMR = 30000 milliseconds
      keep_alive TMR = 9000 milliseconds
    keep_alive count = 1
keep_alive threshold = 18
       RF debug mask = 0x0
```

Comment: Can you provide a full show redundancy states ?

Comment: Are both supervisor modules completely identical (same daughterboards, same memory, and so on)?

Comment: In particular you want to make sure you've got exactly the same software loaded and available on both supervisors, ideally in the same location on both (i.e. disk0:).

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands

```
    show redundancy config-sync failures prc
    show redundancy config-sync failures prc
    show redundancy config-sync failures prc
```

as well as verifying that the active and standby are running the same version of code (this information should be in show redundancy.